# How to fix undefined url using JQuery in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, sweetalert2

i have a problem using sweetalert2 in my codeigniter project, the error is when i click the button confirm to delete, the button can't get all of the url, so the page showing 404 error page, how to fix this error?
this is the javascript with jquery

```
    $('.remove').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const href =$(this).attr('href');
      console.log($href)
      // var getUrl = $(this).attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    
      // var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Apakah Yakin Hapus Data Ini?',
        text: "Data yang terhapus tidak dapat dikembalikan!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ya, Hapus!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Tidak!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          document.location.href = href;
          
        }
      });
    });
```

and this is the button using datatable

```
<td align="center" width="130px">                             
<?php
echo anchor(site_url('pegawai/read/' . $row->user_id), '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="detail"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>');
echo ' ';
echo anchor(site_url('pegawai/update/' . $row->user_id), '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-flat" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>');
echo ' ';
echo anchor(site_url('pegawai/delete/' . $row->user_id), '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-flat remove" id="deletedata" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="hapus"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>');
?>
</td>
```

Comment: `and this is the button` what does the button look like in the browser (not on screen, I mean the HTML)

Comment: `document.location.href = href,true;` looks .... wrong ... do you know what the comma operator does in this line of code?

Comment: i'm using datatable and using array php, and i'm edited the href comma in my javascipt code, do you know what's wrong with my code to get the url?

Comment: what does the HTML for the button look like in the browser - not the PHP, that's not what the browser is getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```js
var href =$(this).parent().attr('href');
```